# "Located at" or "located on"

Tags: sentence-choice

I was doing a biology worksheet, and was confused which sentence to use, or are both correct?

> The stoma is located at/on the underside of the leaf

Is there a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, we use **at** for a point, **in** for a delimited area, and **on** for a surface. This of course is an oversimplification.

In your sentence, "on" fits much much better, as evidenced by the following:

With Ngrams we are limited to 5 words, so:

[image]

But Google search result counts provide a more meaningful view:
"located on the underside of the leaf":  92 700
"located at the underside of the leaf":  4

Based on the above, I think we can safely assume that "on" is the correct form:

*The stoma is located **on** the underside of the leaf.*

Comment: @DialFrost No, you can't. This is the Ngram graph that PPH showed. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=located+at+the+underside+of%2C+located+on+the+underside+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clocated%20at%20the%20underside%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clocated%20on%20the%20underside%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clocated%20at%20the%20underside%20of%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Clocated%20on%20the%20underside%20of%3B%2Cc0 If you click on a one of the dates below the graph, you can see actual references. All of the writers who use **at** seem to have non-english names.